# populate textbox data when clicking one of the items in a listbox

Tags: excel, vba, listbox

I have a listbox (for example: the data comes from `A4:A100` via rowsource in the properties menu)

If someone clicks the top item in the list box (cell `A4`) then in the textbox I would like to show whatever is in the cell next to it (cell `B4)`, the next textbox I would like to show whatever may be in cell `C4` etc...

This is new to me so please go easy with your terminology - So far I have this:

```
Private Sub ListBox1_AfterUpdate()
Me.TextBox1.Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(ListBox1.Value, Range("A1:B1"), 4, False)

End Sub
```

Where am I going wrong?

[image: CLICK HERE TO SEE THE PICTURE]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this:

```
Private Sub ListBox1_AfterUpdate()
    Me.TextBox1.Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Me.ListBox1.Value, Sheets("the_sheet_name").Range("A1:D100"), 2, False)
    Me.TextBox2.Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Me.ListBox1.Value, Sheets("the_sheet_name").Range("A1:D100"), 3, False)
    Me.TextBox3.Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Me.ListBox1.Value, Sheets("the_sheet_name").Range("A1:D100"), 4, False)
End Sub
```

It would be better if you use `range names`, because you can use it "globally" in the workbook, then you can used without the `the_sheet_name` part.

```
Private Sub ListBox1_AfterUpdate()
    Me.TextBox1.Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Me.ListBox1.Value, Range("myRange"), 2, False)
    Me.TextBox2.Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Me.ListBox1.Value, Range("myRange"), 3, False)
    Me.TextBox3.Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Me.ListBox1.Value, Range("myRange"), 4, False)
End Sub
```

Where `Range("myRange")` is a name range inside `Sheets("the_sheet_name")` and with the range of `Range("A1:D100")`

And you can use the code `Me.Textbox1.value =...` in the the sub runtine `ListBox1_AfterUpdate` or `ListBox1_Click` or `ListBox1_Change`

Well, when you use a `VlookUp`, you say:

```
VLOOKUP(lookup_value, table_array, col_index_num, [range_lookup])
```

Mr. VloopUp, look for this value, inside this cells/columns, and return the value in the column number #, and the data is not ordened = False | is ordened = True

If you take the `range("K1:N100")` in the column `K` you don't know in what row you have the value you are looking for, that why you use `VlookUp`, and you say, return the column 1 or 2 or 3 or 4 (`K`-`N`), and if you want the value in the column `O` you need to set the range to `range("K1:O100")`, and ask to return the column 5, because, is not the number of the column in the sheet, is the number of the columns inside the range you selected.

See this for more info about [VlookUp](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/VLOOKUP-function-0bbc8083-26fe-4963-8ab8-93a18ad188a1)

**Edit #2**

As you ask in the comments, the way you can format the value returned from the `VlookUp` is with `Format`

```
a = Format(Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Me.ListBox1.Value, Range("myRange"), 2, False), "dd-mmm-yyyy")
```

Where:

`a` : is a variable, where you can store, can be a `String` or `Variant` type

`Format`: Is the function, that perform the operation

`"dd-mmm-yyyy"` : Is the date format you want. And could be as you need. Ex:

```
mmmm >>> January
yyyy >>> 2016
dd   >>> 02
d    >>> 2
dddd >>> Monday
mmm  >>> Jan
mm   >>> 01
m    >>> 1
```

Have fun with that.

Here you can see more about [Format](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg251755.aspx).

Comment: Fantastic - Worked a treat, thank you! Can you explain this part in more detail please as I dont see how it works 'Range("A1:B100"), 2, False)'

If I changed it to A1:C100, then it will search from the C column instead?

Comment: Unbelievable! Very happy to have found this site and found you so helpful. Thanks, and good luck in your future

Comment: Further questioning, apologies - What you have given me works perfectly, but just noticed that Dates show up in a different format - Is this a simple fix such as amending properties of the textbox?

Comment: Took me a little fiddling around to put it in the right place but it worked! I have learnt more talking to you for the past hour than I have the past few days trying to pick things up over the internet. Highly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

you can avoid VLooking

```
Private Sub ListBox1_AfterUpdate()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim iRow As Long

Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("textbox")
With Me
    iRow = Me.ListBox1.ListIndex + 4

    .TextBox1.Value = ws.Cells(iRow, 2)
    .TextBox2.Value = ws.Cells(iRow, 3)
    .TextBox3.Value = ws.Cells(iRow, 4)
End With

End Sub
```